# Create MySQL Trigger on Insert

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have 2 tables.

Table 1 = myit_table_customer - this table holds customer name, customer id, customer email

Table 2 = myit_table_work_order - this table holds customer name, customer id, customer email, ticket number, time, date etc...

My current problem is that whenever I create a work order, it inserts customer name, customer email, time, ticket number - auto increments, and date but it inserts (0) for the customer ID.

I would like to create a trigger IF on database insert new.email address = email address in myit_table_customer then get the customer ID for that customer from myit_table_customer and assign it to Customer_ID in myit_table_work_order

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tickets AFTER INSERT ON myit_table_work_order

FOR EACH ROW

  BEGIN

    IF CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM myit_table_customer WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = NEW.CUSTOMER_ID) THEN

      INSERT INTO myit_table_work_order (CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (NEW.CUSTOMER_ID);

    END IF;
```

Thanks again.

Comment: you can't write data to the same table

Comment: It is 2 different tables. got it to work with the below codes from fthiella but ran into issues if the user does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think that you need a trigger like this one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tickets
BEFORE INSERT ON myit_table_work_order
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.customer_id = (SELECT id
                         FROM myit_table_customer
                         WHERE email=NEW.email);
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d93ec9/1).

Comment: Hi,

Thank you sooo Much!!

I've modified it to use my tables and columns and it works perfectly.


CREATE TRIGGER tickets BEFORE INSERT ON myit_table_work_order
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.CUSTOMER_ID = (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM myit_table_customer WHERE CUSTOMER_EMAIL=NEW.CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FROM_EMAIL);

Thanks alot once again.

Comment: the script works fine but I encounter error if user does not exist, I would like it to store the email even if the email or customer id does not exist and assign 0 for that customer id. below is a screen shot of the error. Thanks once again.![enter image description here][1] [1]: i.stack.imgur.com/o3Wbt.png

Comment: @user3303594 you could use COALESCE in that case, please see fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec112d/1 or you can allow null data in CUSTOMED_ID column